# Creating a 2 dimensional table of objects in R

Tags: r, data-structures

I have a user define class as follows:

```
Cell<-setRefClass("Cell",
                    fields = list(p="vector", done="logical")
  )
```

I wish to create a tabular data structure where I can have mxn elements each having an instance of my Cell class.

one of the things I tried is:

```
mytable<-array(,dim = c(3,4))
```

I am then setting one of the cells of this array to a instance of my class:

```
mytable[[1,1]]<-Cell$new(p=(1:5), done=FALSE)
```

I get:

*Error in mytable[[1, 1]] <- Cell$new(p = (1:5), done = FALSE) :

more elements supplied than there are to replace*

Not sure if arrays are best suited for something like this, I have tried using matrix and list, but can't seem to achieve what I am trying to do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

S4 objects can be stored in lists, so try this.

```
Cell <- setRefClass("Cell", fields = list(p = "vector", done = "logical"))

mytable <- array(list(), dim = c(3,4)) # make an array of lists

mytable[1,1] <- list(Cell$new(p=(1:5), done = FALSE)) #save new instance as a list    

mytable[1,1][[1]]

# Reference class object of class "Cell"  
# Field "p":
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
# Field "done":
# [1] FALSE
```

You could also use a single list to store of your Cell objects and have an array/matrix maintained as an index to this list, if a two dimensional structure is really needed.